# Netbeans won't recognize php code when asp_tags = true

Tags: php, netbeans

I've turned on [asp_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags) in my PHP config, so now I can echo code like this:

```
<body>
    <h1><%= $this->headerText %></h1>
</body>
```

But Netbeans IDE won't syntax highlight or auto-complete anything in the `<%` block. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need asp style tags? you can echo with `<?= $var ?>` anyway.

Comment: And have you turned in on in project settings?

Comment: @datasage: I'm using XML in my code, so the standard short tags mess it up.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: No I didn't, it's working now. I didn't know that option was in there. Post an answer and I will mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside turning the setting in php.ini, you should also turn it on in netbeans project settings.

Comment: Thanks, Before you suggested this I was looking in the IDE wide "tools->options"